# current location from CoreLocation

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, google-maps

I have an App which launches the google Map App. The code is:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication]; 
[app openURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Obere+Laube,+Konstanz,+Germany&saddr="]];
```

The saddr= should be the current location. I get the current location with

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

NSLog(@"%f,%f", [newLocation coordinate]);
```

The Log displays the correct coordinates like

```
2010-04-05 15:33:25.436 deBordeaux[60657:207] 37.331689,-122.030731
```

I didn't find the right way to transmit the coordinates to the url-string. Does someone can give me a hint how-to?

---

Hmmm, I had the entry in my .h

In my method I use "newLocation" instead your "location". The code is:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

NSLog(@"%f,%f", [newLocation coordinate]);
NSLog(@"%f", [newLocation coordinate].latitude);

storedLocation = [newLocation coordinate];

NSLog(@"Standort neu String: %@", storedLocation);
```

As result I get :

- 2010-04-05 20:28:44.397 deBordeaux[64179:207] 37.331689,-122.030731
- 2010-04-05 20:28:44.398 deBordeaux[64179:207] 37.331689
- Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use **addr** parameter of the URL but **ll**.

You should pass latitude and longitude as

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Obere+Laube,+Konstanz,+Germany&ll=37.331689,-122.030731
```

and you can obtain them from the `CLocation` throught

```
[location coordinate].latitude
[location coordinate].longitude
```

**EDIT:**
First of all you can directly store an object of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and then convert it to a NSString when you need:

```
// in your .h
CLLocationCoordinate2D storedLocation;

// in your method
storedLocation = [location coordinate];

// when you want to ask google maps
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=Obere+Laube,+Konstanz,+Germany&ll=%f,%f", storedLocation.latitude, storedLocation.longitude];
```

Mind that `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is defined as

```
typedef struct {
   CLLocationDegrees latitude;
   CLLocationDegrees longitude;
} CLLocationCoordinate2D;
```

where you have `typedef double CLLocationDegrees`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I understand the usage of "ll=" instead of "saddr=". My problem is, that the code of UIApplication.... is in the -(IBAction)nav.... and the location coordinates later in the #pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate. I can't find a way to "store" the location coordinates in a NSString.